# Excel - keyboard shortcut to double click on format painter

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010

Double clicking on Format Painter has the effect of allowing you to click a few times and apply the same format in all those places.

Alt-H-FP has the same effect as a single click on format painter.

Is there any way to double click on format painter from the keyboard?

Comment: There is not keyboard shortcut for this. Have you tried recording a macro or using VBA?

Comment: Though it's not in the [KB](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-2010-20603861-42b6-4c93-82ec-66924ea9b323#bm2) - the keyboard shortcut ctrl+shft+c *might* copy formatting and ctrl+shft+v might then apply formatting, which you could do repeatedly. I know it doesn't work in 2007.

Comment: @CharlieRB Recording a macro didn't help. I think the macro recorder copies writes code to apply the formatting once you do so, while clicking on format painter in anticipation of applying formatting doesn't register any written VBA code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following steps for excel keyboard shortcut to create a double click on format painter if you are using Excel 2007:

1. Select the cell from which the format is to be copied.
2. Press Ctrl+C (for copying).
3. Select the cells to paste the format.
4. Press Shift+F10, S, T, Enter. This sequence displays the Paste Special dialog box and chooses to paste only the format.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to have a keyboard shortcut for an item is add it on the [Quick Access Toolbar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Quick-Access-Toolbar-6c616455-653c-451c-93f7-96082e98de4d).

Each item on the Quick Access Toolbar is associated to a keyboard shortcut that depends on the *order* of the item in the toolbar and is visible while pressing the **Alt key**:

[image: Quick Access Toolbar]

In this example the Format Painter is accessible hitting *Alt-0-5*, but you can change its position and use for example *Alt-8*.

Once activated the Format Painter, it applies on the first new cell selected, so be aware if you want to use the keyboard to change your position. If you want to avoid the use of the mouse you need to *copy* and *paste special* as in @emailtechsupport answer. My answer is a quicker alternative for *contiguous cells*.